# Object doesn't support property or method 'matches' on Edge

Tags: ecmascript-6, gulp, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, babeljs

I'm using gulp and babel to transcript ES6 into ES5. Here is my code:

**gulpfile.babel.js**

```
import gulp from 'gulp';
import babel from 'gulp-babel';
gulp.src([appDir + 'js/**/*.js', '!' + appDir + 'js/{vendors,vendors/**}'])
        .pipe(babel({
            presets: ['es2015'],
            plugins: ['transform-runtime']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(devDir + 'js'));
```

**package.json**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "*",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "*",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "*",
    "gulp": "*",
    "gulp-babel": "*",
  }
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015"
  ],
  "plugins": ["transform-runtime"]
}
```

Everything works fine on every browser except IE11 and Edge.

IE11 has error:

> 'Symbol' is undefined

Edge has error:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'matches'

I hope that adding this plugin `"plugins": ["transform-es2015-typeof-symbol"]` into .babelrc file will solve the 'Symbol' is undefined problem but not!

Am I missing some special settings or transform plugin for babel?

Comment: You've got `babel-plugin-transform-runtime` in your list of dependencies, but you haven't enabled it in Babel's config. Also generally not a good idea to put two questions in one. Your issue with `matches` is entirely unrelated to Babel or Gulp or ES6.

Comment: I have update the code, but I have new error now: ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: With the build process you've shown, there is nothing that will handle `import` and `export` properly. If you're loading in a browser with module import/export you'll want to use Webpack.

Comment: I'm not using import or export in JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to load https://cdnjs.com/libraries/babel-polyfill from a CDN since you are not using a module bundler. I'd just drop

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/6.23.0/polyfill.min.js"></script>
```

into your page before your other JS files.

As for your error about `matches` you'll have to figure that out by looking at your code. Code using [`Element#matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) will not work on older IE versions because the method either does not exist or goes by a different name.

Comment: Many thanks, this polyfill solved my problem. I also create polyfill for Element matches. I thought that babel will also solve this for me. Why for some functions must be used custom polyfill?

Comment: Babel's transforms concert syntax, so code that would throw a syntax error is converted to code that was valid in ES5 syntax. Providing non-syntactic features is the job of the polyfill. You almost always want both.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, now I finally know why the polyfill is used for :)